# Where can I find a list of possible exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

I understand why, in Python, it's a bad idea to have a *try..except* block that doesn't try to handle specific exceptions.  I can't though, figure out where to find lists of the possible exceptions that can occur with any particular libraries, commands, or methods.

For example, I am currently working with the *decode* statement as follows:

```
in_file = in_file.decode(encoding="ISO-8859-1")  # Turn data from unicode to ascii
```

How do I know what possible exceptions can be thrown?  In a broader sense, where should I look for this kind of information?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in exceptions are listed in the [*Built-In Exceptions* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) of the library documentation. Decoding bytes to Unicode would throw the [`UnicodeDecodeError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#UnicodeDecodeError).

You'd also check the documentation for the method you are calling; you are calling [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) here:

> The default for *errors* is `'strict'`, meaning that encoding errors raise a `UnicodeError`.

Comment: *Built-In Exceptions* lists the exceptions that exist. I think OP wants to learn which of these can be thrown by a specific function.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks!  I'm working through this and I see that decode might throw a UnicodeError.  Taking that to Built-In Exceptions section I see all the attributes available when the error is raised.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a list of all the builtin exceptions, you can find that in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).  The brief description of each kind gives you a basic idea of when they might be used.  (Note that third-party libraries can also define their own exceptions, for which you'd need to look at the documentation for those libraries.)

If you want to know what exceptions a particular function might throw, you need to look at the documentation for that function.  For instance, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) for `decode` indicates that it might throw a UnicodeError.

Comment: I found this documentation useful for when you want to create your own exceptions... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions